# gunicorn giving error while run apache airflow webserver

Tags: python, linux, airflow, gunicorn

When I try to initialize apache airflow webserver. I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gunicorn': 'gunicorn'
```

This issue is resolved when I do this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/python-env/bin
```

1. Why above line is resolving the error?
2. What can I do so that I don't have to export PATH everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error, so thank you for your workaround. I have combined it and my suggestion is to put PATH concatenation to `/etc/sysconfig/airflow` (or another file that you use for `Service` definition in `EnvironmentFile`)